# (Swagger 2.0/ Connexion) None type is not of type 'string'

Tags: python, flask, openapi, connexion

I am trying to create one simple post API through python connexion. Here is my api yaml file:

```
swagger: "2.0"

info:
  title: "My first API"
  version: "1.0"

basePath: /v1.0

paths:
  /potential:
    post:
      operationId: api.data.create_potential_data
      summary: Create the potential data
      parameters:
        - name: alertCategory
          in: body
          required: True
          description: The potential API request AlertCategoryDto object with settings of alert category (categorySystemName, alert Kpis etc.)
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/alert"
      responses:
        201:
          description: Successfully created potential data


definitions:
  alert:
    properties:
      systemName:
        type: string
      name:
        type: string
      moduleSystemName:
        type: string
```

But for one of the attributes `name` we **allow user to enter `null` value.** And if they really do this, we will get the `error: None type is not of type 'string'`

So is there anyway in swagger 2.0 to make the attributes nullable? Cannot find much information online. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Connexion — Control "Type" Key in 400 Response Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40431714/python-connexion-control-type-key-in-400-response-errors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Danilo's help I found the answer from connexion's documentation here:

[image: https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/request.html]

In a word, adding `x-nullable = true` will resolve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should put down type: string
nullable: true

From here I obtained the information
[This link](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/)

It would be something like this:

```
definitions:
  alert:
    properties:
      systemName:
        type: string
      name:
        type: string
        nullable: true
      moduleSystemName:
        type: string
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Danilo! The only issue is that the `nullable` function only works for openAPI 3.0 whereas python connexion is still using openAPI 2.0

Comment: Try type: [string, null]
Not sure if it works. Get the info here: https://github.com/zalando/connexion/issues/226 and the guy wrote that it worked

Comment: Thank you. I finally found the answer from connexion's documentation